# RecyclerView с возможностями ViewPage 'a

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, recyclerview

Дано: Список элементов и их состояний
Цель: Используя RecyclerView добиться отображения только трех элементов списка.

В принципе как решить проблему доводки элементов в RecyclerView я понял.
Но чтобы видно было только 3 элемента?
[image: Пример]

Comment: "как решить проблему доводки элементов в RecyclerView я понял"  -- какую проблему?

Comment: что вы понимаете под "доводкой"?

Comment: @s_klepcha если вытащили не весь элемент из-за края экрана а только часть то его нужно или полностью скрыть или полностью показать